# Operation Not Implemented Exporting Excel (Data Only) Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to deploy an application to a client's server, but export to Excel (Data Only) is not working, giving me the "Operation Not Implemented" error.  It isn't a problem with the report, because I have over 50 reports with standard fonts, some of them very simple, and the export fails for all of them.

I have the feeling the incorrect version of exportmodeller.dll and crtslv.dll are being used, because the client seems to have some sort of logon script which appears to copy a CR8.5 version of the crystal reports libraries and register them with COM.

I attempted to automatically make a manifest file for my main executable to force it to use the correct version, but this didn't change anything.

Might I have missed something, or do you think I'm completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Turns out the correct version of the CR libraries are being loaded.  I'm not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed the problem down to being related to a format issue with the report.  It just happens to not affect my Windows 7 dev machine.

On the Windows Server 2003 R2 (x64) machine, if I remove the Print Date and Print Time special fields, it will export to xls (Data Only) successfully.

I did also notice that the process loads ATL.DLL on the Windows 7 box, but not the Windows Server box.  I gather that could somehow be related.

So, *a* solution to my problem is to remove those fields.  Full points if anyone can offer some advice which would prevent me from having to edit all of my reports.

Update: If I use a specific date/time format in my reports instead of "System Default Format" it also works.

Comment: Weird - I've never seen that with the older versions of Crystal. Do you see the same behaviour if you use the data date and time instead of the print date and time?

Comment: Yes, I did see the same behavior.  The issue was present using Crystal Reports Developer XI, XI R2, and now 2008.  But only after upgrading to Visual Studio 2008 for development.  It worked just fine using the CRXI viewer for years before that in VS2003.